# IllegalArgumentException will show an error when added String value

Tags: android, illegalargumentexception

I'm new to Android development and it is a basic question.

I have tried to replace IllegalArgumentException with the String value. How to replace this that Android error will not be shown?
Need help.

It wil not work:

```
R.string.msg_log1
```

getString(R.string.msg_log1)

My code is the following:

```
          if (myPhone == null || myPhone < 0) {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("Data requires valid phone");
```

Comment: What exactly do you want to replace, the `"Data requires valid phone"`? And what does "not work"?

Comment: Is it in an activity/fragment or adapter..?

Comment: `throw new IllegalArgumentException(getString(R.string.msg_log1));`

Comment: what do you want the code to do instead of throwing exception?

Comment: Throwing my exception is intended report to know all activities which are positive or negative (errors). I thought it can be stored my hard-coded text into strings.xml and not as a Toast message as some proposed. All options were wrong like R.string.msg_log or getString(R.string.msg_log1). See Data requires a valid phone. This is hard-coded text.

Answer (score -1):

If you are in an Activity you could use it like this.

```
if (myPhone == null || myPhone < 0){ 
    Toast.makeText(this, getResources().getString(R.string.msg_log1), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
}
```

make sure you add the string with the name msg_log1 to the strings.xml

Comment: My hard corded text is not a good solution.

Data requires valid phone should be replaced using Strings.xml file. Toast is not valid due to IllegalArgumentException which should not be passed inside Toast but Logcat.